# Can I used simple sql commands in django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I want to select data from multiple tables, so i just want to know that can i used simple SQL queries for that, If yes then please give me an example(means where to use these queries and how).

Thanks.

Comment: Unless you have a compelling reason not to, you should investigate whether using the ORM will be possible for your particular case. It actually does a very good job of creating queries, and works even if you change DBMS down the track (ie, move from sqlite to postgres). You can fetch related data in one query, and there are lots of other nice bits too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer django documentation

[Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

[Perform Raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/